# Proper cut-off voltage for SLA battery in 120°F+ environment?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging

This is related to **[this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/313017/appropriate-float-voltage-for-sla-battery-in-120f-environment?noredirect=1#comment729163_313017)** question as well, in which I inquired about the most appropriate float voltage for a battery that would be in very high ambient temperatures, as the float voltage should compensate for temperature changes to avoid over-charging.

A question I'd asked in the comments, and was recommended be a separate question here, is the following:

> What compensation is appropriate for the cut-off voltage of a sealed lead-acid battery? If ambient temperature is 130-140 degrees [inside a vehicle], and I'm lowering the float voltage by .5Volts to compensate (0.003mV per cell per degree celsius over 25°C, 30°C difference to 55°C)

As an example, if my cut-off voltage would normally be 10.8Volts for a deep-cycle battery at 25°C, **would that value be lower for a battery in an ambient temperature of 55°C? If so, how much / how would I calculate the compensation?**

---

*Tagged as battery charging because I wanted to tag as battery discharging and there wasn't one for it... feel free to edit if there are more appropriate tags.*

Comment: Sealed lead acid is an ambiguous term. Do you mean AGM?

Comment: @GlennW9IQ I don't have a specific description of the battery type. From what I've seen, there's AGM, Gel cells, and 'flooded' 
 as options (right?), I'm not sure which of these this is. A link to the one I purchased: https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00KQX5GSC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Float voltage is lowered at higher temperature to prevent gassing. On discharge the open-circuit voltage is barely affected, but internal resistance is lower so voltage will be a bit higher at high current. At end of discharge the internal resistance increases and voltage drops rapidly, so a fixed cutoff voltage should be fine.

If ambient temperature is normally 55ºF then battery life will be severely reduced.

[Deep Cycle Battery FAQ](https://www.solar-electric.com/learning-center/batteries-and-charging/deep-cycle-battery-faq.html#Temperature%20Effects%20on%20Batteries)

> "Battery life is reduced at higher temperatures - for **every 15
>   degrees F over 77, battery life is cut in half**. This holds true for
>   ANY type of Lead-Acid battery, whether sealed, gelled, AGM..."

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, ambient will unfortunately be 55C for periods of the year (Summer in Phoenix Arizona, battery installed in the back of a vehicle). Good reference with the note about battery life being cut in half per 15 degrees over 77. I'd like to find a way to correct this problem but I'm not aware of anything I could do in my region to help this; it's just that warm outside in Arizona.

Comment: Shade and a fan could help, and white paint. The air temperature is probably not 55C very often, as that is right around the hottest air temperature ever recorded on Earth.